# NullReferenceException being thrown despite debugger showing objects C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have defined the following class:

```
public class PerceptronNetwork : NetworkBase
{
    Neuron perceptron { get; set; }

    public PerceptronTrainer trainingMethod;

    public PerceptronNetwork(Neuron aNeuron)
    {
        this.perceptron = aNeuron;
    }

    public double train(TrainingTemplate trainingTemplate, int extMaxGenerations)
    {
        // This is simple but the ideea is suposed to be that in larger networks here
        // I do a foreach over the neurons
        double error =  this.trainingMethod.trainNetwork(trainingTemplate, perceptron,
                                                         extMaxGenerations);
        return error;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use the train method from my main function I get the error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

pointing to the `perceptron` object.

Despite that when I hover over every object in the function call trainingTemplate, perceptron and extMaxGenerations they all seem to be pointing to proper values.

Did I declare or instantiate them wrong in some way ?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "pointing to the perceptron object"? Is the exception definitely in `train`, or is it in `trainNetwork`? (As an aside, it's a good idea to get into the habit of following .NET naming conventions... and keeping your fields private.)

Comment: Show the full stack trace here please.

Comment: and trainingMethod? where is initialized?

Comment: We don't see where `aNeuron` (and therefore `perceptron`), `trainingMethod`, `trainNetwork` and `trainingTemplate` are created. They all could be `null`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that would not generate an exception until they were _used_ - and in that case the stack trace would point to `trainNetwork` (or a lower method).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: ... or `trainingMethod`. The other objects could throw an excpetion within the method `trainNetwork`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullReferenceException` is not thrown when you pass a null parameter, it is thrown when you try and access a member property/method/field on a null reference.  In your case it means that `this.trainingMethod` is `null`.

If `trainNetwork` had validation code to verify that the incoming parameters were not null, you would most likely get an `ArgumentNullException` with the name of the parameter that was null indicated.

If `trainNetwork` tried to reference an instance member on a null value that you passed in, the stack trace would originate from that method, not from `train`.

Comment: Ummm... passing a null parameter *could* result in a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Yes but from the method that _uses_ it, not from the method that _passes_ the parameter.

Comment: This was it, sorry for making such an obvious error (never code when you're tired from work)

Comment: @GeorgeBora Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that `this.trainingMethod` is instantiated. From your code it doesn't seem to be.

If it is then you will have to show the full stack trace.